# How to call Node.js service inside jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, mongodb

I am .net developer. I decided to learn Node.js by using a sample. I created a node.js service  to collect data from Mongo db database. And Then I have a HTML webpage . I used a simple jquery code to get this node.js web service. But I hot this error : Requested JSON parse failed.

My Db :

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58568264477db6913051a0cf"),
    "Name" : "yusuf"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58568381477db6913051a0d0"),
    "Name" : "leyla"
}

My Server Code: (Node.js)

```
'use strict';
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var router = express.Router();

app.get('/Notifies', function (req, res) {

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Test', function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var coll = db.collection('Notifies');

        coll.find({}).toArray(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {

                res.send(result);
            }
        })
    })

});

var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
})
```

***Jquery :***

```
    var GetAllNotifyTypesFunc = function () {
        console.log("notify");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/Notifies',

            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            async: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                var str = '';
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function (idx, elem) {
                    console.log(elem.Name);
                    str += "\"" + elem.Name + "\"" + " : " + "{ \"!type\": \"bool\" }" + ",";
                });

                str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);;
                str = "{" + str + "}";
                localStorage.removeItem("alarms");
                localStorage.setItem('alarms', str);
            },

            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                var msg = '';
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                } else {
                    msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                }
                console.log(msg);
            }
```

This above code return to me this error: **Requested JSON parse failed.**

Comment: 1. Why use `jsonp` as Accept header? If you say "Okay, the response would be `application/jsonp` **you must provide a callback to decode the response**. Remember, json != jsonp. 2. If your service is in another domain, just enable CORS on server for your client domain and set `dataType` to `json`. For more information: `Request JSON parse failed` happen because you doesn't specify the callback for JSONP response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 'parseerror' is generated I think data is fetched by not in correct JSON format.

Try using `res.json` instead of `res.send` in *NodeJS code*
If not working use **POSTman** like HTTP client and check response for '/Notifies'. You will be able to use [JSON parser](http://jsonparseronline.com/) like this to check whether response is in correct JSON format.